# DataGrid unable to deselected modified item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I have a WPF application with a DataGrid.
This DataGridis bound to an ObservableCollection that contains a bunch of models.
The selection mode of this DataGrid is set to Extended.

When ever a item is currently selected, and then receives an update (something of the selected item changes during a refresh for example) and then the user attempts to select another item, it does not deselect the previous item.

The OnselectionChanged fires, but does not contain the previouse item, and there seems to be no way to deselect it.

The code that runs this (clean wpf application using .net core 3.1)

The DataGrid, that (as you can see) doesn't store any of the selected items either.

```
            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                  x:Name="ItemsDataGrid"
                  SelectionMode="Extended"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
        </DataGrid>
```

The items, which is a simple Observable Collection

```
private ObservableCollection<Window> _items = new ObservableCollection<Window>();

public ObservableCollection<Window> Items
{
    get => _items;
    set => SetProperty(ref _items, value);
 }
```

And the code that changes the item, it just grabs the first item, and adds a new Dimension

```
 private void ChangeItem()
    {
        var rand = new Random();

        Items[0].Dimensions = new Rect(rand.Next(1, 100), rand.Next(1, 100), rand.Next(1, 100), rand.Next(1, 100));
    }
```

And on request, here the code that adds the items to the ListBox

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedItemsListBox.Items.Clear();

        foreach(var item in ItemsDataGrid.SelectedItems)
        {
            SelectedItemsListBox.Items.Add(item);
        }

        SelectedItemsListBox.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

Here the application is just opend, and the "Refresh" button has been clicked to show 3 items
[image: No Selected Items]

Here the first item has been selected, the "Change Item" button has been clicked that modified the Dimensions, also note how this item now shows it's description below, this is a listbox that displays all currently selected items and was refreshed (including a listbox.clear) after clicking "Display selected Items".

[image]

Here the 3th item has been clicked, selecting it, and should in turn also deselect the previously selected item, but as the listbox shows, it is still selected.

[image]

I already trimmed the issue down to this point, it ended up not being my selection method, it wasn't the MultiSelector i used, nothing of the UI frameworks i used, this barebone solution still has the issue putting me at a loss for words and out of idea's as to wat it might be.

Comment: The `DataGrid` appears to behave properly. It's the `ListBox` that displays too much items. Since the `ListBox` also works properly (except you changed its behavior), it must be the logic which adds the selected items to the `ItemsSource`. Funny that especially the selection part, which you know is not working, is completely ignored and not shown in your post.

Comment: Updated the post to include the listbox update, that being said, wat your looking at here is a test app, i created after over 2 days of sruggling in an actual application. The selected items stay selected regardless of how i populate the listbox, Binding the items to a property does the same, i stored the MultiSelector and checked its collection, and it was still alive and well in there as well. listend to the OnSelectionChanged also didnt show any change to the old item

Comment: Why is it named `SelectedItemsDataGrid`, isn't it a `ListBox`? From your images there is only one item selected as there is only a single red row. It's the way you are treating the collections.

Comment: Updated the code again, changed the name. It was still called DataGrid as i simply copied some of the xaml over and added selected infront of the name. It is in reality pointing to the listbox shown below the DataGrid

Comment: Could you suggest how i should threat the collection, as i mentiont. binding the the OnSelectionChanged https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.onselectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1 never fires for the deselection of the top item. Using a Multiselector to bind it to a ObservableCollection also never updates with the removal of said item. Looping through all SelectedItems of the DataGrid itself (which is a 100% .net item without modification from my part) still shows the item as a selected item. as shown above, regardless of what the visual representation says

Comment: Are the properties defined in the code-behind file?

Comment: Only the event handler was defines in code behind, the rest is all defined in a viewmodel using mvvm

Comment: If you are using MVVM you shouldn't handle `Window` in your view model. Better create a data model to represent a `Window` by holding relevant data.

Comment: Thank you, for simplicity sake i tried to keep the sample as small as i could while maintaining the same behaviour my larger application displays. in normal cases i would do it differently, this is just to (in a simple way) show what happens and how it happens, so it might be easier for someone else to try themself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are observing is related to your `GetHashCode` implementation.

From your posted class definition (on Pastebin), I was able to learn that your data items are implementing `IEquatable` and in this context also override `object.GetHashCode`.

**You implementation computes the hash code based on mutable fields!**
This should be generally avoided as it can lead to unexpected behavior (like you are experiencing right now).

> "In general, for mutable reference types, you should override GetHashCode() only if:
>
> - You can compute the hash code from fields that are not mutable; or
> - You can ensure that the hash code of a mutable object does not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on
>   its hash code."

(Microsoft Docs: [Notes to Inheritors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#notes-to-inheritors))

The problem with mutable fields is that they can change *while* the object is used in a hash based collection.
If the field used for the hash code computation changes, then the hash code would change too and as the result the stored value of the original hash key would be lost.

Now you must know that `DataGrid` and `Selector` in general uses a hash table to store the selected items to improve lookup performance. Since your type implements `IEquatable`, the `DataGrid` is tempted to use the value returned by `GetHashCode` as key, because it assumes an overridden implementation.
This implementation of `GetHashCode` is checked by the `DataGrid` for reliability before used, but obviously this reliability check is not taking the mutability of the fields used for computation into account. Of course, this would require reflection. It seems quite reasonable to avoid reflection and just test the result of `GetHashCode` being constant after consecutive calls.

With this in mind we are now able to explain the behavior:

- An item is selected and stored in a selected items hash table
- `DataGrid` uses the item itself as key for the hash based selected items backing collection to improve lookup speed
- Since the items implement `IEquatable` the hash table happily calls `GetHashCode` on the selected item to get an object hash as key for the value (the selected item)
- You now modify the item by editing a cell of the `DataGrid`, which also results in an undesired change of the computed hash code
- Next you select a different item. The `DataGrid` now tries to remove the previous selected item(s) from the selected items collection. But since the item's hash code has changed, the lookup won't return any item. Therefore the old and deselected item(s) remains in the selected items collection.

The solution is to follow the guidelines and avoid overriding `object.GetHashCode`, because in your case:

- You **cannot** compute the hash code from fields that are not mutable (read-only) AND
- You **cannot** ensure that the hash code of a mutable object does not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on its hash code.

So removing/fixing the `GetHashCode` override will fix the issue.

---

### Implementation improvements

Add a `SelectedItems` collection of type `ObservableCollection` as the binding source for the `ListBox` and add a `DataGrid.SelectionChanged` event handler:

**View model**

```
private ObservableCollection<Window> _items = new ObservableCollection<Window>();
public ObservableCollection<Window> Items
{
    get => _items;
    set => SetProperty(ref _items, value);
 }

private ObservableCollection<Window> _selectedItems = new ObservableCollection<Window>();
public ObservableCollection<Window> SelectedItems
{
    get => _selectedItems ;
    set => SetProperty(ref _selectedItems, value);
}
```

**View (code-behind)**

```
private void OnDataGridSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var viewModel = this.DataContext as ViewModel;
  foreach (Window addedItem in e.AddedItems.Cast<Window>())
  {
    viewModel.SelectedItems.Add(addedItem);
  }
  foreach (Window removedItem in e.RemovedItems.Cast<Window>())
  {
    viewModel.SelectedItems.Remove(removedItem);
  }
}
```

**View**:

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Extended"
          SelectionChanged="OnDataGridSelectionChanged">
   ...
</DataGrid>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample. i implemented exactly as shown here, except that i added a display member path to the listbox, so it actualy shows the item description.

https://hostr.co/file/FZxmqKoN4RDJ/Updatedwayofhandling.png 
as you can see in this image, it still shows both as selected items,

Comment: Can you do a clean and rebuild and retry while I test the code?

Comment: Yes, not an issue. if you want i can even upload my test project itself if that were to be a prevered way of doing it.

Comment: deleted the bin and obj folders, cleaned and rebuild the project, but still seeing the same results im afraid.

Comment: I have tested the above implementation using a collection of double as items source. It works as expected. Can you please remove everything else so that your project contains nothing but the two controls.? No code should modify the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` except the data binding set on this property. Maybe replace the `Window` with `string`or `double` values too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i did as you said and removed everything, added a simple model with an id and text, when i select the item, then change something about it, and then select another item it works as expected. this ofcourse comes with the question, what changed. This leads me to question if my equality check inside the models might somehow effect it? so might test that next

Comment: That's what I was expecting. Would you mind to post the model class?

Comment: I assume you mean the original model, here is a pastebin link, altho if you want i could add it to the main post (its rather long) https://pastebin.com/gzX5UMt2

Comment: Just noticed that your  `Equals` doesn't check for reference equality. Usually you want the references to be equal too. Does this error only happen after you modify the first item?

Comment: [recommended Equality pattern](https://pastebin.com/Gt63brKG)

Comment: Right so the model is a rather out of the ordinary one in that it rarly happens to be the same model we work with, this beccause its constructed from a list of processes. We use some extension methods to convert the data to the original model, but before we are able to do so an equality check needs to execute, which thus always fails when the items don't reference the same item in memory. hence that it uses a custom check, unless you know a better way of handling that, that being said, it doesnt seem like the selected items checks for the equality based on my testing

Comment: After slowy adding stuff in, it seems that adding the GetHashCode suddently breaks it

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CCau73FN This is the model im currently testing with, removing the GetHashCode fixes the issue, adding it back and the double selection appears again. based on my testing, note that i implement ModelBase just to allow the UI to be notified of changes in the model itself

Comment: Can confirm that inside my full application the GetHashCode is called just before the OnSelectionChanged fires off, all i can assume is that DataGrid uses the HashCode to Identify items, which after an item changed might no longer matches up? Removing the override for HashCode seems to fix it, question that would remain is, should GetHashCode be overwritten? i

Comment: After a bit more testing (by looping the selected items and printing the hashcode) it actualy seems that they do match, regardless of overwriting the GetHashCode, whch leaves me to wonder why removing the override helps

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain the behavior. Please revisit it to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused between selecting a cell and selecting an item (row) of DataGrid.
Replace DataGrid and, I think, you yourself will understand the cause of your problem:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
              x:Name="ItemsDataGrid"
              SelectionMode="Extended"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}">
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

If @BionicCode correctly written about implementing IEquatable in a collection item, then remove it.
While this is not the cause of the problem, it can lead to others.
The ItemsControl (the DataGrid is derived from it) does not guarantee correct operation when the equal items are present in the collection.
Equality of elements is determined by the Equals() and GetHashCode() methods.
These methods are also used in many others in the internal implementation of DependecyObject.
Therefore, it is advisable to use a reference type for data intended for WPF and not change the default Equals() and GetHashCode().
If you need to compare by value, you must either use an immutable implementation (possibly a struct) or create methods similar to Equals() and GetHashCode(), but them with other names.

You can also complement the ListBox with a binding to SelectedItems and it will display the selected in real time:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=ItemsDataGrid}"/>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't help. Please read my answer to understand the true nature of the problem.

Comment: The type itself doesn't have to be immutable. The fields used for the computation must be immutable e.g., by using read-only fields.

Comment: It's also not advisable to remove `IEquatable` from the type's signature. It is recommended to implement this interface. But in case  you can't guarantee a constant hash code and can't prevent the type from being used in a hash based collection you should not override `GetHashCode`. Also it's not about `ItemsControl`. The common type is `Selector`, which is responsible to handle selected items. This type uses a hash table to store selected items.

Comment: @BionicCode ,I haven't looked at the implementation of the collection item.
Maybe you're right.